# tc command does not affect on two processes in a same machine

Tags: tc

I am wondering why tc command does not work as expected.
I set the command like the following

```
tc qdisc add dev eno0 root handle 1:0 tbf rate 50mbit burst 25kb limit 250kb
```

where I'm expecting outbound communication is simulated over 50Mbps bandwidth. Now, I'm trying to let two processes communicate with each other on a same machine using local ip address (say, 192.168.0.4) associated with `eno0`.

In order to know the affect of the `tc` command.
I used `iperf` command on two processes `A` and `B`.

At process `A`, I ran `iperf -s`.

At process `B`, I ran `iperf -c 192.168.0.4`.

However, the observed bandwidth rate is approximately `300Mbit/sec`. (Not around `50Mbit/sec`!).
The machine is located under the router that can process 1Gbps at most.
And, the LAN cable is capable to deal with enough bandwidth rate.

When I tried to do the same thing using two different machines under the same router where the role of process A is on another machine while the role of process B is on the machine having IP address `192.168.0.4`, observed bandwidth is around `50Mbit/s`.

How can I get `50Mbps` simulation on the same machine??
Is it impossible to do that?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The same machine routes traffic from itself to itself locally, using the `lo` interface. It will not emit any packet on the wire (`eno0`) for this traffic. You could use the same rule, but on the `lo` interface instead, but more tweaking is needed: for example the default MTU of 65536 changes the tbf behaviour (found in logs: `sch_tbf: burst 25600 is lower than device lo mtu (65550) !`):

```
# ip link set lo mtu 1500
# tc qdisc add dev lo root handle 1:0 tbf rate 50mbit burst 25kb limit 250kb
```

Anyway there would be slight differences. For example, `lo` is a layer 3 interface and thus doesn't have Ethernet overhead, which will alter results.

You can use instead network namespaces to do more isolated simulation, example:

```
# ip netns add host1
# ip netns add host2
# ip -n host1 link add dev eno0 type veth peer netns host2 name eno0
# ip -n host1 link set lo up; ip -n host2 link set lo up
# ip -n host1 link set eno0 up; ip -n host2 link set eno0 up
# ip -n host1 address add 192.168.0.4/24 dev eno0
# ip -n host2 address add 192.168.0.5/24 dev eno0

# tc -n host2 qdisc add dev eno0 root handle 1:0 tbf rate 50mbit burst 25kb limit 250kb
```

Term1:

```
# ip netns exec host1 iperf -s
```

Term2:

```
# ip netns exec host2 iperf -c 192.168.0.4
```

If your goal is to involve actual external hardware, it's probably possible using [macvlan interfaces in VEPA mode](https://backreference.org/2014/03/20/some-notes-on-macvlanmacvtap/) instead of *veth* interfaces, still in network namespaces. This probably requires configuration on the external switch (or router) too, and don't do IP collisions.